# Spark/SQL - SUM LAST 5/n days of counts over Week_Dates without ID column

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have below table With first 3 columns i.e. Counts, Week_Start, Week_End.

I am using Spark with SQL and API/Scala and need to show column 4th (Five_Week_Count) which is sum of Current week counts + last 4 weeks Count.

I tried window function with range but it fails without an ID column.
Can you have a look and please advise ? If you need more info please let me know.

| Count | Week_Start | Week_End | Five_Week_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 572 | 2021-03-13 | 2021-03-19 | 336288 |
| 106065 | 2021-03-06 | 2021-03-12 | 371623 |
| 82878 | 2021-02-27 | 2021-03-05 | 393972 |
| 59128 | 2021-02-20 | 2021-02-26 | 475994 |
| 87645 | 2021-02-13 | 2021-02-19 | 655908 |
| 35907 | 2021-02-06 | 2021-02-12 | 637359 |
| 128414 | 2021-01-30 | 2021-02-05 | 620200 |
| 164900 | 2021-01-23 | 2021-01-29 | 576378 |
| 239042 | 2021-01-16 | 2021-01-22 | 508091 |
| 69096 | 2021-01-09 | 2021-01-15 | 459419 |
| 18748 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-08 | 495833 |
| 84592 | 2020-12-19 | 2020-12-25 | 530895 |
| 96613 | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-18 | 486940 |
| 190370 | 2020-12-05 | 2020-12-11 | 641346 |
| 105510 | 2020-11-28 | 2020-12-04 | 502672 |
| 53810 | 2020-11-21 | 2020-11-27 | 556047 |
| 40637 | 2020-11-14 | 2020-11-20 | 693209 |
| 251019 | 2020-11-07 | 2020-11-13 | 877883 |
| 51696 | 2020-10-31 | 2020-11-06 | 687154 |
| 158885 | 2020-10-24 | 2020-10-30 | 756603 |
| 190972 | 2020-10-17 | 2020-10-23 | 597718 |
| 225311 | 2020-10-10 | 2020-10-16 | 406746 |
| 60290 | 2020-10-03 | 2020-10-09 | 181435 |
| 121145 | 2020-09-26 | 2020-10-02 | 121145 |

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a row for every week, then use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(count) over (order by week_start rows between 4 preceding and current row) as five_week_count
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add one column for WeekNumber you can do this:

```
Select Count,
Week_start,
Week_end,
WeekNumber,
(Select SUM(count) from t where WeekNumber between t.WeekNumber and t.WeekNumber - 4)
From Table t
```

Comment: If you don't see a good way to find WeekNumber, I can edit my code to fit your need.